Ubuntu Terminal is not working the cursor is blinking
My terminal on Ubuntu is not working. The cursor is blinking, but I cannot type anything. What should I do to fix this issue?

press Ctrl-C to cancel whatever it is doing. Then check your configuration-files (.profile, .bashtc and more), You probably have made some changes in one of them recently. Fix whatever you have changed,

I Pressed Ctrl+C but it doesn't cancel . yeah i changed .profile file. Then this occurs.

What did you change in .profile ?

Use Files (Nautilus), right click the file(s) and Open in Text editor,  then edit / change it back or find and correct any fault(s).

Note: CTRL+Pause/Break (upper right corner of keyboard) is a more potent CTRL-C.

First, turn on "Show hidden files" with ctrl+H, and then open your .profile file with a text editor.
Replace it with the following contents (you can optionally take its backup first).
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi

You may also have to restore the bashrc file.

Thank you . i tried this now but still the terminal cursor is blinking

Did you try closing and opening the terminal? By any chance, is the .bashrc file also affected?

I close  and reopen the terminal even i restart the laptop

Thanks . you are right the issue with .bashrc file. Now terminal is working. Thank you very much.

you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark, if it worked for you.
